# Use dataframe column to subset entire dataframe and apply function row-wise (anomaly detection)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outliers, anomaly-detection

Suppose I have a table like this

| code | neighbours | t_min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abr007 | abr018, abr030, abr032 | 16.2 |
| abr018 | abr007, abr030, laz246 | 20.9 |
| abr030 | abr007, abr032, cmp015 | 21.9 |
| ... | ... | ... |

It contains observations of temperature for some weather stations having a unique id given by `code`.

In order to find outliers I added a column with neighbouring stations (`neighbours`), so as to compare the value of every station with the distribution given by the neighbouring observations: if it falls outside the [1st, 99th] percentiles interval I flag it as anomaly.

I've achieved this pretty easily by looping over the rows, then subset the original dataframe `df[df.code.isin(row.neighbors)]`, compute percentiles over this subset and compare it with the station observation. However, this is relatively slow (about 8s for ~3000 rows) and I have the feeling that I could get rid of the loop and vectorize the operation by grouping the original dataframe over `code`.

I've been thinking about this for a few days now and couldn't come up with an easy solution to wrap the same operation into a function that perform well when grouping...is that possible?

---- Details ----

Here is a snippet of the code that I currently use

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    # Grab all the neighbours and take care of
    # - excluding the station itself
    # - excluding any station that has already been flagged as anomalous
    subset = df[(df.code.isin(row.neighbors)) & (
                df.code != row.code) & (~df['anomaly'])]
    q1, q99 = subset['t_min'].quantile([qn1, qn2]).values
    if ((df.loc[df.code == row.code,'t_min'].item() < q1) or
         (df.loc[df.code == row.code, 't_min'].item() > q99)):
        df.loc[df.code == row.code,'anomaly'] = True
```

Neibhours are found using a `BallTree` algorithm (that part is actually pretty fast!).

Comment: Could you paste the code which you currently use?

Comment: Sure, I've added a small snippet of the code with the relevant part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a better way by creating ad-hoc arrays.
If you consider

- `variable = df['t_min'].values`
- `indices` holds all the indices of the neighbours per station

Then I just compute the quantiles beforehand

```py
var_quantiles = [np.nanquantile(variable[ind], [qn1, qn2]) if len(
        ind) > 5 else np.array([-np.inf, np.inf]) for ind in indices]
```

then construct a `pd.Interval` column that holds the limits given by the quantiles

```py
df['interval'] = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(np.array(var_quantiles).T[0] - thresh, 
np.array( var_quantiles).T[1] + thresh, 
closed='both')
```

Then I can just check individually the stations that fall out of the interval

```py
df[anomaly_column_name] = df.apply(
        lambda x: True if x[var] not in x['interval'] and not np.isnan(x[var]) else False, axis=1)
```

This takes less than a second instead than 12 :)